# Speed listening

Tags: phonetics, reference-request, spoken-language, speech-recognition

I have just heard that there are people out there (mostly blind people) using screen readers at overspeed, achieving speech rates twice as high as usual, and even higher.

What I want to know is: Are there quotable references for the statement above, and what listening speech rates are confirmed in the literature.

Comment: Excellent question! I've also heard anecdotes about this and would love to see some hard numbers on it.

Comment: Lots of people listen to TV or podcasts at increased speed. That's not notable at all.

Comment: Listening to overspeed playback is nothing remarkable.  Shouldn't we be hunting, if we care about this at all, for 'quotable references' comparing comprehension of overspeed playback with comprehension of normal speed playback?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Of course, comprehension is crucial here, so the reference should not only give data on the rate of overspeeding (though this alone can be interesting) but also measure the comprehension somehow (e.g., by asking question on the heard content)